# How to access the data from the previous block of Ethereum block chain through the block number?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am new to block chain. Suddenly I got a question did we can able to access the previous block data from the Ethereum block chain by block number.

For example I have created a block1, block2.

block1 has data 'apple' after that I have changed the data to 'banana' so new block is created block 2. I know if we call the get data function then it going to give output banana but in case I want to access the data from the block1 through the block number as 1 how to access it?

There is any way to access the data from previous block it there please help my question to solve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can access previous state at a specific block using offchain tools. For example the web3js method `call()` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth.html#call)) allows you to specify a block number that you want to query.

However, onchain contracts do not have access to previous blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The Graph Protocol can help index historical information if you need to access to it laster.

Answer (score 0):

You can check block information by typing in the block number here on Bitquery's Explorer. here's an example: https://explorer.bitquery.io/ethereum/block/17179989